# Paypal Integration With MVC, how to send shopping cart item details to PayPal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to implement PayPal payment gateway in an MVC 4.0 site. There are many links on StackOverflow that show how we can use PayPal in various scenarios, however most of them need us to configure products and items on Paypal first.

Suppose I have some coupons or discount on bulk purchase then I need to define them upfront on PayPal portal.

Is there any way that I can handle all these rules on my site? so on the site I apply all the coupons/discount etc and then send the final shopping cart items to PayPal for payment.

This is the first time I am trying to integrate PayPal and I am really confused.

Comment: basically you can setup all the payment,transction information on your shopping cart/site and pass the information to paypal, what difficulty are you facing in doing the same?

Comment: Vimal most of the articles that I am reading show that you have to create product on PayPal sandbox, assign price, dicsounts etc. I could not find any post that shows how to send all this info to PayPal. What is that option called express checkout? Sorry but I am really new to PayPal api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate all the payment options on your site, you will need to use Clear text buttons.
**Example:**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="A attention de M. Montaigu">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="BE">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="LIEGE">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="Zaventem">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="4000">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

To pass multiple items, you need to make use of `cart` option.

**Example**
:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="vimal.android@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="beach ball">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="towel">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20">

<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Here you are populating all the payment variables and sending it to PayPal server to process the request. You can find the list of variables [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) including `discount` variable that you may want to use.

Additionaly, since you asked about [express checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/), this is an advanced way to integrate PayPal on your website and it more advantageous than normal HTML buttons and it uses API calls to make the communication with PayPal unlike the website payment standard buttons which just uses HTML form tags.

Comment: Vimal thank you for your answer, this does clear a lot of confusion  in my mind, can you please update me on how can we send multiple item details also?

Comment: Thanks, super cool and simple answer, basically its all about sending information in certain format to PayPal.